# how to make swipe elite plus volte phone

Tags: 4g

I have swipe elite plus and and want to make it volte but problem is there is no update from swipe and there is no custom rom available for swipe elite plus.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your phone supports voLTE, in which case  the guide to activate it is found here: [How To Enable Jio VoLTE calling on any Android Smartphone](http://www.rootupdate.com/2016/04/activate-volte-4g-hd-calling-on-android.html).

Alternatively, you can use  [Jio4GVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jio.join) to make HD voice or video calls over 4g. For more information please refer to this website: [Make any smartphone to support voLTE (HD voice and video calls with Jio4GVoice](https://www.datareign.com/4g-3g-2g-smartphones-volte-jiojoin-app.html)

Hope this helps